# How to solve this example using Poisson Distribution?

Tags: poisson-distribution

Particles are suspended in a liquid medium at a concentration of 4 particles per mL. A large amount of the suspension is thoroughly agitated, and then 3 mL are withdrawn . Let $X$ be the number of the particles in the 3 mL. Answer the following:

a- The distribution of X is a Poisson distribution, what is its parameter ($\lambda$)?

b- Find the probability that no particle is withdrawn from the 3 mL.

c- Find the probability that one particle is withdrawn from the 3 mL.

Comment: I solved "a" as following but I do not know if it right or not :        if there are 4 particles in 1 ml then there are 12 particles in 3 ml . but in this case should I consider the value 12 lambda ?

Comment: Please add the self-study tag and read the [tag info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). What do you know about Poisson distributions?

Answer (score 1):

a) Yes, you're correct, the value of $\lambda$ should be 12.

What have you done for the other two?

b and c both look right to me.

Comment: 'b' P(X=0) = e^-12 . (12)^0 / 0! = 6.144 x 10^-6

Comment: "c" P(X=1)= (12)^1 . e^-12 / 1! = 7.37 x 10^-5

Comment: Looks right ...